# How do I ignore a node module with ignore-loader + webpack-node-externals?

Tags: webpack

When I use [ignore-loader](https://github.com/cherrry/ignore-loader) to ignore imports from node modules, it appears to have no effect when I'm also using [webpack-node-externals](https://www.npmjs.com/package/webpack-node-externals). However, it does work when I import files from within my own repo. For example:

```
{
  externals: [
    nodeExternals(),
  ],
  target: node,
  module: {
    rules: [
      { test: /\.css$/, use: "ignore-loader" },
    ],
  },
}
```

With this rule, relative imports of CSS files get ignored, but imports of CSS files from node modules cause syntax errors. So, `import "./foo.css"` causes no problems, but `import "react-tippy/dist/tippy.css"` causes a syntax error:

```
/Users/jessepinho/.../node_modules/react-tippy/dist/tippy.css:1
(function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) { .tippy-touch{cursor:pointer!important ...

SyntaxError: Unexpected token .
```

This problem only comes up when including `nodeExternals()`. It seems that webpack-node-externals prevents not just bundling of node modules, but also even letting loaders process them.

Any idea how to work around this? Thanks!

Comment: I tried to reproduce this, but everything works fine. Can you share your whole webpack.config.js?

Comment: @lukas-reineke Ah! In the process of trying to create a minimal reproduction of the issue, I realized the problem only comes up when using webpack-node-externals. It prevents node modules from being bundled into the main file, but apparently also prevents any loaders from being used on them as well...? I've updated the question to include this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The webpack-node-externals plugin will filter out node_modules from the normal bundling and add them to externals.
Externals in webpack work as described [in the documentation](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/externals/):

> Prevent bundling of certain imported packages and instead retrieve
>   these external dependencies at runtime.

This means the ignore-loader will not work for these files.

An easy fix is to add css files to the whitelist of webpack-node-externals

```
externals: [nodeExternals({
    whitelist: [/\.css/]
})],
```

Comment: You nailed it  Thanks so much!

Comment: glad i could help